# can you tell me what is problem or why is error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, syntax-error

hello dear developers,

i did't understand why is error. can tell me why is error and where is my fault. thanks in advanved

```js
(function() {
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
  const h1 = document.getElementById('h1')

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var hexvalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    var hexcolor = '#'
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexvalues.length);
      var hexcolor += hexvalues[random]
    }
    h1.style.color = hexcolor
  })
})()
```

if i use this then it's working `var hexcolor = hexcolor + hexvalues[random]`

Comment: You want `hexcolor += hexvalues[random]` not `var hexcolor += hexvalues[random]` you already declared `hexcolor` as a start. Leaving it the way you have it is also invalid as you're appending to undefined.

Comment: Hi @sayeed - please can you include the error you are seeing in your question.

Comment: please post the error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your main issue is coming from the fact that you are redeclaring `hexcolor` within your `for` loop. When you create a variable using `const`, `let`, `var`, you cannot use the `+=` operator. The `+=` operator means add to the end of (append). Thus, if you are creating a variable for the first time you will have nothing to append to, and so you need to use `=` to assign the variable.

To fix your issue, you need to remove the `var` from `var hexcolor`, so you are modifying the `hexcolor` you declared outside your for loop.

See working example below:

```js
(function() {
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
  const h1 = document.getElementById('h1')

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var hexvalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    var hexcolor = '#'
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexvalues.length);
      hexcolor += hexvalues[random]
    }
    h1.style.color = hexcolor
  })
})()
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>

<h1 id="h1">Color me</h1>
```

Comment: Badly worded. You can re-declare a variable in a loop and append do it. The problem is the type of the variable when it's re-declared and the operator used.

Comment: @Adriani6 I've tried to clear up my explanation a little

Answer (score 0):

When you use `var hexcolor += hexvalues[random]` you are using `+=` with initializing variable. You shouldn't use `var` again as its declared outside

```js
(function() {
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
  const h1 = document.getElementById('h1')

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var hexvalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    var hexcolor = '#'
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexvalues.length); 
      hexcolor += hexvalues[random]
    }
    console.log(hexcolor);
    h1.style.color = hexcolor
  })
})()
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button> 
<h1 id="h1">Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
(function() {
      const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
      const h1 = document.getElementById('h1')
    
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var hexvalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
        var hexcolor = '#'
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexvalues.length);
           hexcolor += hexvalues[random]
        }
        h1.style.color = hexcolor
      })
    })()
```

```html
<button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
    <h1 id="h1">Header text</h1>
```